# I'm not able to import Charts when getting openpyxl.chart

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a simple chart using openpyxl but it's not recognizing the modules (BarChart, Reference, Series, LineChart, ScatterChart) when I call it. See below:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, PatternFill, fills, Border, Side
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series, LineChart, ScatterChart

#drawing a chart
    values = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row= 1, max_col = item[11], max_row = items[count_isos] )
    chart= LineChart()...
```

I tried simply inserting the bib as usual : from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series, LineChart, ScatterChart but it's not working

Comment: Please include the full exception message.